# Unknown USB Device (Device Descriptor Request Failed)

Tags: drivers, sd-card

I'm on Windows 8.1 Pro and my SD card slot on my Toshiba Satellite (L505D-S5965) doesn't work anymore. It suddenly stopped the day before yesterday and I know it's not internal damage because when I did a system restore it worked for about 3-5 Minutes before not working again. Is it a registery problem or is it something else?

Comment: Try to boot a live cd (e.g. ubuntu) and see if you can access it there. This would help rule out a software issue (registry or otherwise)

Comment: Have you tried with more than one card?

Comment: @harrymc Yes. I tried 2 microSD cards and 1 regular sized.

Comment: For an intermittent problem, have you considered a possible hardware failure? The suggestion of trying a live linux cd is a possible test.

Comment: This is a driver problem. I faced the same problem when connected my Lumia to my PC with USB. It always says USB device not recognised. I simply restarted both my PC and phone and tried connecting five times. Finally, installing device appeared and now it's working fine.

Answer (score 4):

It could be a problem with the driver. You should go to Device Manager under Control Panel and uninstall the driver, then download the driver from the Toshiba website and reinstall again.

Comment: I tried this with a x64 driver, but It's telling me that this driver isn't. I right clicked the info and it said it successfully installed but it didn't show up and it still didn't work.

Comment: You should download the driver from the Toshiba website for your specific model and OS and install that using the installer, or if that doesn't work then manually. You may have to remove the existing driver first from inside device manager. So first, find your device in device manager, uninstall the driver and then try to install the one from the Toshiba website.

Answer (score 2):

For an intermittent problem, have you considered a possible hardware failure?

A good test is to boot a live Linux CD to see if the problem still happens.
This can show whether the problem is hardware or software/driver
(although why would the driver fail so suddenly?).